# Streaming a variable from a file

Tags: matlab, bigdata

Currently, I am working with MATLAB 2014a. I have a lot of data in matrices written in plenty of mat files. I have to make some calculation as if all matrices would be the one big block of data. The problem I am facing is that each file already takes about 800MB and there will be tens of them. I am estimating something arounf 30 - 60 GB of data.

My idea, although don't know if physically possible, is to write all of them into one big variable in disk. But another problem is how I can load such a big block into memory. I was thinking if MATLAB provides anything similar to streaming. E.g., I would pass a variable into a function that would map the block in a disk and data would be loaded from a disk instead of memory. It should not matter in function perspective where the data are loaded from.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`matfile`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matfile.html) function (introduced in  R2011b):

> `m = matfile(filename)` creates a MAT-file object, `m`, connected to the MAT-file named `filename`. The object allows you to access and change variables directly in a MAT-file, without having to load the variables into memory.
>
> The partial loading and saving that the matfile function provides requires less memory than the load and save commands, which always operate on entire variables.

You can load/save *parts of variables* from/to the file. See the examples in the linked documentation.

Comment: I have not checked it. I have been wondering if I could pass a matfile object with reference to a variable instead of regular matlab variable stored in memory.

Comment: My point about suggesting `matfile` was: load the data from each of your mat files, and "add" that data from each file to the same matfile variable. That way the matfile variable will contain all your data. You can then read parts from that single matfile variable for processing

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend upgrading to R2014b if possible, and then using [`mapreduce`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/mapreduce.html) with [`datastore`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datastore.html). This is specifically designed for processing large amounts of data (i.e. when you have too much to fit into RAM) from multiple files.

Comment: No, I am afraid 2014a is currently the only version available for us. I know 2014b has it. This is why I've mentioned MATLAB version in my post.